# Postgres Update Number Values in a JSONB field to be text

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a JSON column and some of the values in it are numbers but I want all the values to be text. For example, I have {"budget": 500}, but I want it to be {"budget":"500"}. I have tried using the JSONB_SET function but even after postgres returns N rows updated, when I go to retrieve the records, they are still numbers. I was hoping that somebody may have encountered this issue. Here's what I've tried that isn't working.

```
UPDATE my_table
SET data = JSONB_SET(data, '{budget}', data->'budget'::text)
WHERE data ? 'budget' = true;
```

Since this is a very large table, hardcoding values is not feasible. If anybody knows why this isn't working or if there is something that does work, please let me know, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enforce converting a JSONB number to text with the function `quote_ident()`:

```sql
UPDATE my_table
SET data = jsonb_set(data, '{budget}', quote_ident(data->>'budget')::jsonb)
WHERE data ? 'budget'
-- you can add this condition to avoid updating non-numbers
-- AND jsonb_typeof(data->'budget') = 'number'
```

Note that `data->'budget'::text` does nothing as the cast refers to `'budget'`, not a JSON object and the expression is equivalent to `data->'budget'`.